# WINAPI C - CreateFileMapping fails with error 8 - ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Tags: c, file, winapi, memory, mapping

I'm working with file mappings on Windows but having some troubles with them.
First off, I have the necessity to partially map a file and setting the start and the end of it dynamically.

My code is the following:

```
long fiveMB = 5 * pow(2, 20);
for(int i=0;i<parts;i++){
    long start = (i)*fiveMB;
    long end = (i + 1)*fiveMB;
    long realEnd = end;
    if (roundedDim<realEnd)
        realEnd = dim;

    long chunkDim = realEnd - start;
    LARGE_INTEGER fileMapStart.QuadPart = (start/granularity)*granularity;
    LARGE_INTEGER mapViewSize.QuadPart = (start%granularity) + chunkDim;
    LARGE_INTEGER fileMapSize.QuadPart = start + chunkDim;
    long offset = start - fileMapStart.QuadPart;

    HANDLE fileMappingH= CreateFileMapping(fileH, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, fileMapSize.HighPart, fileMapSize.LowPart, NULL);

    if(fileMappingH == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || fileMappingH == NULL){
       printf("Error mapping file: %d\n",GetLastError());
       CloseHandle(fileH);
       return 1;
    }

    char *mapView = (char *)MapViewOfFile(fileMappingH, FILE_MAP_READ, fileMapStart.HighPart, fileMapStart.LowPart, mapViewSize.QuadPart);
    if ((LPVOID)mapView == NULL) {
        printf("Error mapView: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(fileMappingH);
        CloseHandle(file);
        return 1;
    }

    mapView += offset;

    /* doing all the stuff */

    UnmapViewOfFile((LPVOID)mapView);
    CloseHandle(fileMappingH);
}
```

As far as I know, only MapViewOfFile requires the starting byte to be aligned with the system granularity, so I didn't bother to fix the maximum file mapping size for that.

I tried this code on a 1448 KB file (printing out dim I get **1482159 bytes**) while calculating the available memory via GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memstatus) and **memstatus.ullAvailVirtual** I get **2092208128 bytes** but still stuck on having the CreateFileMapping call failed and with error code 8, `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

I also tried calling **CreateFileMapping(fileH, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL)** to memory map the whole file, but instead there were problems on **MapViewOfFile**, error 5, `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, since I successfully did it with mmap on a Linux version of the same project.

Thanks anyone who may help.

---

EDITS:

- c was a leftover, I actually meant i
- added UnmapViewOfFile and CloseHandle calls

Comment: c is undefined.

Comment: at first - call `CreateFileMapping` in loop - this is design error. you need call this only once. at second on error `CreateFileMapping` return 0 but not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` - no sense check it for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

Comment: about error `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` - several ntstatus codes is converted to this error. so here lost on win32 layer. need call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` - may be you got for example `STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG`- this mean that you set size for section more than file size and because you use `PAGE_READONLY` file can not be extended

Comment: @stark fixed it

Comment: @RbMm so you mean I have to use once CreateFileMapping on the whole file and then using MapViewOfFile to locate the part I need?

Comment: @EmanueleGiona - of course. only once. no sense call it more time. and call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` - `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` can be from `STATUS_NO_MEMORY` or from `STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG`

Comment: @RbMm sorry to ask, but which header defines RtlGetLastNtStatus()?

Comment: @EmanueleGiona - you can define it as `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) NTSTATUS __stdcall RtlGetLastNtStatus();` and link with `ntdll.lib` or get this procedure address in runtime as `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "RtlGetLastNtStatus");` and call it also after `MapViewOfFile` fail - because too many different status mapped to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - yo lost too many useful info with `GetLastError`

Comment: `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`, `STATUS_ALREADY_COMMITTED`, `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` - all this is converted to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. i for example guess that you got `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`

Comment: simplest way for you - `LONG (*RtlGetLastNtStatus)();
  *(void**)&RtlGetLastNtStatus = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"),"RtlGetLastNtStatus"); ` and i almost sure that `RtlGetLastNtStatus();` return `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE` after `MapViewOfFile` and `STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG` after `CreateFileMapping`

Comment: `so I didn't bother to fix the maximum file mapping size for that` - this is root for your errors

Comment: The program just crashes when `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` is called, and I just don't know how to troubleshoot that.
I fixed the sizes for the MapViewOfFile but not for CreateFileMapping

Comment: so you mistake get address of `RtlGetLastNtStatus`, despite it soo easy task

Comment: About the size of the `file map object` being the sum of the file offset + num of bytes, does consume that big in RAM? For example, I have a very huge file which cannot be opened due to RAM constraint, but I only wanted to examine a few bytes from a certain offset. Because the `file map object` has a size which adds the file offset is also huge, can i be able to examine the few bytes from that offset?

Comment: @ifelsemonkey the only RAM the file mapping uses is the one specified by the `MapViewOfFile` call; so if you know which is the right file offset and how many bytes you want to check from there on, you simply do that by correctly specifying the last parameter for `MapViewOfFile`, which in my code is `mapViewSize.QuadPart`. [Here](https://github.com/emanuelegiona/PONE2016_17/blob/546edb1d245d8337c22767b075793e36750f2369/win/wserver.c#L265) you can see the whole code, link to the peculiar `MapViewOfFile` function call

Comment: So if i want to examine 3 bytes at offset `2^32 - 100`, then it will only use around 3 bytes of RAM and not the gigabytes as indicated in the offset. Right? I'm clarifying this because in Microsoft docs in `CreateFileMapping` the `dwFileMapSize` parameter is described as `"size of mapping object"`

Comment: @ifelsemonkey yes, but in `CreateFileMapping` you have to put the whole file size; in order to examine your 3 bytes at a given offset has to be specified through `MapViewOfFile`: be aware that each size involved in such calls has to be aligned with the filesystem granularity! So if you want to read those 3 bytes, you have to map the a chunk of file which correctly starts at the expected granularity, with 3 bytes size and then take the offset into account to localize such bytes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I know, MapViewOfFile only requires the starting byte to be
>   aligned with the system granularity, **so I didn't bother to fix the
>   maximum file mapping size for that.**

this is root of error - really from [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx)

> *dwNumberOfBytesToMap [in]*
>
> The number of bytes of a file mapping to map to the view. **All bytes
>   must be within the maximum size specified by CreateFileMapping**. If
>   this parameter is 0 (zero), the mapping extends from the specified
>   offset to the end of the file mapping.

if we use 0 as *MaximumSize* in [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) the maximum size of the file mapping object is equal to the current size of the file. and :

> if an application specifies a size for the file mapping object that is
>   larger than the size of the actual named file on disk and **if the
>   page protection allows write access** (that is, the *flProtect*
>   parameter specifies **PAGE_READWRITE** or **PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE**),
>   then the file on disk is increased to match the specified size of the
>   file mapping object.

and about `GetLastError` and win32 errors at all. the errors in most case returned from kernel as `NTSTATUS` code. the win32 layer converts the specified `NTSTATUS` code to its equivalent system error code via [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx). unfortunately this conversion **not injective** - the many different `NTSTATUS` code can convert to same win32 error and we lost sensitive info here.

so in some case much more better call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead of `GetlastError()` - this give to as much more info about error.

> `CreateFileMapping` call failed and with error code
>   `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.

based on error `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` we can think that not enough memory in system (`STATUS_NO_MEMORY`). but also another status - `STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG` converted to the `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`. the `CreateFileMapping` is thin shell over [`ZwCreateSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx) the `STATUS_SECTION_TOO_BIG` returned when:

> The value of *MaximumSize* is too big. This occurs when either
>   *MaximumSize* is greater than the system-defined maximum for sections, or if *MaximumSize* **is greater than the specified file and the
>   section is not writable**.

and this is exactly your case: you use `PAGE_READONLY` in call `CreateFileMapping` - so *section is not writable* and *fileMapSize* is greater than the specified file (size for the file mapping object that is larger than the size of the actual file on disk)

> `MapViewOfFile` return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

again `GetLastError()` plays here with us a cruel joke. the initial status is not `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` how we can wait, but `STATUS_INVALID_VIEW_SIZE`. this status also converted to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. the `MapViewOfFile` got it when not all bytes within the maximum size specified by `CreateFileMapping`

and call `CreateFileMapping` multiple time in loop - this is design error - need call this api only once, before loop. in loop only exist sense call `MapViewOfFile`. the test code can be:

```
void TestMap(PCWSTR lpFileName, ULONG dwChunkSize)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FILE_STANDARD_INFO fsi;
        if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileStandardInfo, &fsi, sizeof(fsi)))
        {
            if (HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                if (ULONG n = (ULONG)((fsi.EndOfFile.QuadPart + (dwChunkSize - 1)) / dwChunkSize))
                {
                    LARGE_INTEGER ofs = {};
                    do 
                    {
                        if (PVOID pv = MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_READ, ofs.HighPart, ofs.LowPart, --n ? dwChunkSize : 0))
                        {
                            UnmapViewOfFile(pv);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            RtlGetLastNtStatus();
                        }
                    } while (ofs.QuadPart += dwChunkSize, n);
                }

                CloseHandle(hSection);
            }
            else
            {
                RtlGetLastNtStatus();
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    else
    {
        RtlGetLastNtStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: the only mistake I was making was rounding up the file dimension, and that would cause the failure of `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()`

I even read so many times that documentation page, still I wouldn't figure out how much the WINAPI is strict over this, while POSIX let me do it without troubles

thanks for all the effort!

Comment: Excellent answer.